# Guava Android expireAfterWrite issue

Tags: android, caching, guava

We are trying to use the library on Android for TimedEviction. The items in the cache are expiring as soon as we overwrite an existing item.

We are building the cache as follows:

```
private Cache rssiMap;

RemovalListener removalListener = new RemovalListener() {

@Override
public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification removal) {

    }
    };

    rssiMap = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
               .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
               .removalListener(removalListener)
               .build();
rssiMap.put(device, rssi);
```

Is there something wrong we are doing with the code or is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior.

Actually, client code doesn't care WHEN the elements are expired, right? Client code does care about WHAT final cache values are.

The `RemovalListener` focuses on WHAT is evicted instead of WHEN. 
JavaDoc of  `RemovalListener.onRemoval()`:

> Notifies the listener that a removal occurred at some point in the
>   past.

By the way, I recommend use `Cache.get()` instead of `Cache.put()`.

From JavaDoc of `Cache.put()`:

> Prefer get(Object, Callable) when using the conventional "if cached,
>   return; otherwise create, cache and return" pattern.